# Carrierwave displays image after failed validation

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Using Carrierwave to upload an image and it renders the image on a page when validation failed.

**Scenario:**

Visit user edit page where it includes the user's avatar image.
Upload a new avatar image greater than 4 MB and hit update.
Validator fails as the file size is greater that 4 MB.
User edit page renders with correct error messages.

**Problem:**

Image is displayed on the rendered edit page. It disappears if I revisit the user edit page, and can confirm it did not save in the db.

I am also using '`file_validator`' gem.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
 validates :avatar, file_size: { less_than: 4.megabytes }
  ... 
end 


class UsersController < ApplicationController
 ...
 def update
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Your account settings were successfully updated."
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**Ref :** https://github.com/johnTheDudeMan/foodme

Comment: I've tried the instructions from the CarrierWave wiki to delete cache directories, but they do not delete after failed validation.  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Delete-cache-garbage-directories

Answer (score 0):

Putting the following line in my #update seemed to fix the problem. Now I just need to figure out how to clear cache because carrierwave still keeps those failed uploads.

```
@user.avatar = @user.avatar.retrieve_from_store!(@user.avatar.identifier)
```

Comment: There is a 'How to: clear cache directories' in the gem's wiki. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I couldn't get it to work. I was trying to delete the tmp dir from the update function at first, and then even manually but all files and directories are still there.

Comment: Also now MiniMagick processes the resize of an image and thus allows invalid image through, because it resizes it and brings it below file size max. I need to disable this and try again with clearing cache.